# проверка элемента jquery

Tags: jquery

есть код который выводит категории в виде селекта с подкатегориями...

```
$(function() {
    var $categoryWrap = $('#categoryWrap');
    $categoryWrap.on('change', 'select', function () {

        var $this = $(this),
        category_id = this.value;

        $this.nextAll().remove();

        if(category_id == '0') {return false;}

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=ajax/SubCategoryList',
            data: {
                id_cat: category_id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#typeCategory').remove();
                if (data != '') {
                    var $newSelect = $('<select name="subCategory" id="subCategory" data-id="' + category_id + '"/>');
                    $newSelect.append('<option value="0">- <?=$text_select?> -</option>')

                    $.map(data, function(v) {
                        $newSelect.append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>')
                    });
                    $categoryWrap.append($newSelect);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

этот код динамически создает списки селект пока есть подкатегории. как сделать проверку существует ли последний селект на странице или нет
.is() .length не помогли

Comment: что есть "последний селект"?

Comment: последний селект это последний выподающий список подкатегории при выборе категории, например есть категория с подкатегорией и у нее еще одна подкатегория и т.д. так вот последний селект это последняя загруженная подкатегория

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("select[data-id='" + category_id + "']").length > 0) {
  // существует 
}
```

Comment: этот вариант тоже не подошел

Comment: @vkt Вариант хороший, не сомневайтесь.

Comment: я ни капли не усомнился, да вот только по факту не помогло!!!

Comment: @vkt Потому что Вы недостаточно хорошо объяснили, существование какого элемента Вы пытаетесь проверить. В редакторе вопроса есть кнопка "Фрагмент кода". Попробуйте создать работающий пример.